# how to make Gnu/Linux trust a certificate that's trusted by Windows out-of-the-box?

Tags: curl, openssl, ssl, certificates

There is a server with a broken SSL chain, as reported by [this SSL check](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=betriebsheft.vog.it):

[image: SSL check report]

I know this is a problem that *should* be solved on the server itself, but sometimes this is hard to have fixed (I'm not the admin of the server).

The thing is, that Chrome/Mozilla/Edge on Windows **trust the site certificate anyway**:

[image]

However, in a Gnu/Linux deployment (Ubuntu 18.04 in Docker) the certificate is *not* trusted:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I tried `update-ca-certificates` and even imported the Globalsign Root certificate. `update-ca-certificates` reported a duplicate certificate in that case. Anyway, nothing works.

### How to reproduce

Using Docker:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:18.04

# within container:
apt-get update
apt-get -y install curl
curl https://betriebsheft.vog.it  # <---- "unable to get local issuer certificate"
```

How can I make Gnu/Linux trust this certificate?

*PS: The same certificate is [deployed correctly on another server](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=vog.it).*

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking something he can't influence himself. He said he *can't modify anything server-side*, so this probably belongs to superuser I think, as it describes a problem having no solution client-side.

Comment: I am specifically asking for a **client-side** solution. I can't influence the server, but I have full control over the client O/S (Ubuntu) and I want this specific O/S installation to trust the certificate just like other O/S (Windows) do. It's not about fixing the HTTPS site for others.

Comment: That is exactly why I believe it is off-topic here. I'm off to go, see you.

Comment: The question is about [using/administering a *nix system and applications packaged therein](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Did you add the certificate in the docker container (vs installing it in the host)?

Comment: @xenoid: yes, in the container: `wget https://secure.globalsign.net/cacert/Root-R1.crt && openssl x509 -inform DER -in Root-R1.crt -out Globalsign-R1.pem -text && cp Globalsign-R1.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/Globalsign-R1.crt && update-ca-certificates` or what I also tried: `wget https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem && curl --cacert cacert.pem https://betriebsheft.vog.it`

Comment: What browser are you using in Ubuntu (the difference is probably in the browser).

Comment: @Vlastimil the most common error is to see things the complete opposite of what they are. I think you have made this error.

Comment: Most web-browsers have a way to add certificates, but beware. By going around the security, you are disabling the security. You will make your-self vulnerable to man-in-the-middle-attack.

Comment: You don't control the server, but you still can report the problem to the person who does control the server.

Comment: As a Java developer, I run into this alot.  The browsers trust the broken chain; Java does not.  I just tell the admin to fix it because anything else compromises security. I didn't see an option in `curl` to "behave like the browser", but it's certainly frustrating when it's out of your control.  It would be nice if the various implementations were more  consistent, it would prevent this half-configured mess in the first place.

Comment: To answer those suggestions about not loosening security: I'm just trying to  replicate the behaviour of a very common browser (Chrome) and I guess the Chrome team takes security very seriously. Having such a mechanism in Linux/CURL could be acceptable I think. Also, I'm not trying disabling cerrificate checks altogether. About contacting the admin: true, but not possible if you don't know in advance which servers you are going to connect to (in case the address is dynamic)

Comment: ...I didn't know about AIA before.

Answer (score 11):

The real fix for this is to ensure that your server presents **all** certificates in the chain and not just the end-entity (server) certificate.

Point your server administrator to [RFC 5246 Section 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2) which clearly states that *This message conveys the server's certificate **chain** to the client.*

---

If your admin refuses/can't do this for some reason, your alternative option is to try and get `curl` to work with the malformed handshake.

According to a message on the Curl mailing list:

> > Can someone confirm if cURL supports (or not) intermediate certificate?

> Yes it does.
> All ca certificates have a certificate chain going up to the root. The ca
> bundle you use with curl needs to consist of the certs for the entire chain.
>
> / daniel.haxx.se

You should be able to add the Root CA and all intermediates certificates to a bundle and point `curl` to it using the `--cacert <file>` option.

As your browsers work, you can access the correct CA certificates from there.  On the certificates tab (different for each browser, but I'm sure you'll figure that one out), view the certificate chain.  Double-click the Root CA first *Globalsign Root CA - G1* and on the **Details** tab, click on **Copy to file...**.  Save it as `root.cer`.  Do the same with the *AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2* and save it as `issuing.cer`.  Join the two together in a single file (e.g. `chain.cer`) and use that as the argument to `-cacert`.

As kindly pointed out by @A.B. the missing certificate can also be found [here](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1223298-alphassl-intermediate-certificates).

---

Your browsers work because they cache CA certificates.  If you've navigated to a correctly configured website at some point in the past, whose certificate was issued by the same CA as your server's certificate, it will be cached by the browser.  When you subsequently visit your incorrectly configured site, your browser will use the CA certificates in its cache to build the chain.  To you, it seems like everything is fine, although behind the scenes, the server is mis-configured.

Note that on Windows, IE/Edge and Chrome share the same cache, while Firefox uses its own.

In addition to the above, IE/Edge and Chrome (as they share the same crypto stack) will use an extension within certificates called the *AuthorityInformationAccess*.  This has a *caIssuer* option which provides a URL from which the end-entity certificate's CA certificate can be downloaded.  Therefore, even if one of these browsers hasn't cached the missing certificates from previous browsing, it can fetch it if required.  Note that Firefox doesn't do this, which is why sometimes Firefox can show certificate errors when IE/Edge and Chrome seem to work.

Comment: It's not my server, so can't modify anything server-side. I tried to use the CA bundle from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html (since Firefox trusts the certificate) and pass it using `--cacert cacert.pem` but CURL still does not accept the certificate.

Comment: It _is_ your server.  Run `echo q | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect betriebsheft.vog.it:443` and you will see only one certificate being presented by your server.  There should be two - the end-entity cert (which is presented) and the issuing CA - the Alpha SSL - SHA256 - G2 certificate.  The latter isn't being sent by the server, but should.

Comment: @garethTheRed : I understand that the server does not present all certificates, but **the server is not under my control** (that's what I meant with "not my server"). I'm just trying to access an API on an foreign server. Under Windows, none of my browsers complain about the certificate, only Linux/Debian/Ubuntu does.

Comment: @A.B: thanks a lot! Installing all the root certificates from that page **solved the issue**. However, I'd like to understand why that manual step is necessary.

Comment: interesting. How comes also Firefox also accepts the certificate (you said it doesn't use this extension)? Is it because the "missing" certificate was perhaps installed system-wide by Chrome/Edge?

Comment: that's because firefox accepts the cert that i removed my comments: I didn't want to mingle more than needed. Ok now I get it (thanks to @garethTheRed). I'll put back the comment

Comment: The missing **intermediate** cert (as mentioned by @garethTheRed) can be found there: https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1223298-alphassl-intermediate-certificates . OP initially only tried to add the *root* cert which was probably already in place, thus achieving nothing.

Comment: @UdoG: repeating what was already told, this manual step is necessary because the server is misconfigured: it should have provided the missing cert itself. The difference is now the intermediate cert will have more privileges (eg: a cert which was signed with an obsolete algorithm will now be trusted instead of creating an error)

Comment: I feel your pain (and see that you are being misunderstand stood). However please do not blame the secure systems, they are just doing their job, and protecting you. Is the solution to loosing your house keys, to remove the locks?